# C++ Pthreads: Algorithm to run N threads simultaneously when >N threads must be run each iteration

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, pthreads

I have a program that needs to run a function M times per iteration, and those runs can be parallelized. Lets say I'm limited to running N threads at a time (say by the number of cores available). I need an algorithm that will make sure I'm always running N threads (so long as the number of threads remaining is >= N) and that algorithm needs to be invariant to the completion order of those threads. Also, the thread scheduling algorithm should not claim significant CPU time.

I have something like the following in mind, but its clearly flawed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdlib>

void *find_num(void* arg)
{
    double num = rand();
    for(double q=0; 1; q++)
        if(num == q)
        {
            std::cout << "\n--";
            return 0;
        }
}


int main ()
{
    srand(0);

    const int N = 2;
    pthread_t threads [N];
    for(int q=0; q<N; q++)
        pthread_create(&threads [q], NULL, find_num, NULL);

    int M = 30;
    int launched=N;
    int finnished=0;
    while(1)
    {
        for(int w=0; w<N; w++)
        {
            //inefficient if `threads [1]` done before `threads [2]`
            pthread_join( threads [w], NULL);
            finnished++;
            std::cout << "\n" << finnished;
            if(finnished == M)
                break;
            if(launched < M)
            {
                pthread_create(&threads [w], NULL, find_num, NULL);
                launched++;
            }
        }

        if(finnished == M)
            break;
    }
}
```

The obvious problem here is that if `threads[1]` finishes before `threads[0]` there is wasted CPU time, and I can't think of how to get around that. Also, I'm assuming that having the main routine waiting on `pthread_join()` is not a significant drain on CPU time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advice against respawining threads, it's a rather serious overhead. Instead, create a pool of N threads and submit work to them via a work-queue, a rather standard approach. Even if your remaining work is less than N, the extra threads will not do any harm, they'll just stay there blocked in the work-queue.

If you insist on your current approach you can do like this:

Do not wait for threads with `pthread_join`, you don't need it, since you're not communicating anything back to the main thread. Create the threads with the attribute `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED` and just let them exit.

In the main thread, wait on a semaphore, which is signaled by each exiting thread - in effect you would wait for *any* thread termination. If you don't have `<semaphore.h>` for any reason, it's trivial to implement it with mutexes and conditions.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdlib>

sem_t exit_sem;

void *find_num(void* arg)
{
    double num = rand();
    for(double q=0; 1; q++)
        if(num == q)
        {
            std::cout << "\n--";
            return 0;
        }

    /* Tell the main thread we have exited.  */
    sem_post (&exit_sem);
    return NULL;
}

int main ()
{
    srand(0);

    /* Initialize pocess private semaphore with 0 initial count.  */
    sem_init (&exit_sem, 0, 0);
    const int N = 2;

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init (&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate (&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    for(int q=0; q<N; q++)
        pthread_create(NULL, &attr, find_num, NULL);

    int M = 30;
    int launched=N;
    int finnished=0;
    while(1)
    {
        for(int w=0; w<N; w++)
        {
            /* Wait for any thread to exit, don't care which.  */
            sem_wait (&exit_sem);

            finnished++;
            std::cout << "\n" << finnished;
            if(finnished == M)
                break;
            if(launched < M)
            {
                pthread_create(NULL, &attr, find_num, NULL);
                launched++;
            }
        }

        if(finnished == M)
            break;
    }
}
```

Anyway, I would again recommend thread-pool/work-queue approach.

Comment: So it seems that with this system there would be no sense in using more than one `pthread_t` (we could just start all threads with the same one). I'm not familiar with work queues, how are they implemented? are they part of pthread? Also, just curious, but how does `sem_wait` or `pthread_join` avoid the problem of excessive looping while waiting for a flag?

Comment: @MattMunson, I edited it a bit, you don't need any `pthread_t`. Work queues is a common design pattern, not a part of POSIX Threads, just google it. The functions `sem_wait` and `pthread_join` (and many others) cause the thread to *block* (if needed) and the kernel to schedule other threads, until something cause the blocked thread to be woken up. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state it's part of the very first basics taught in any operating systems course.

Comment: +1 for an alternative, efficient approach that does not involve join and the semaphore solution.  I can only presume that, somewhere out there, there is a reccommended book for Computer Science 101: 'How To Use Threads', that says '1) Always join threads and wait for the thread to finish. 2) Don't bother reading up on OS synchro primitives - they are too difficult to use.  3) Spend a lot of time adding a scheduling layer on top of the OS - the team of highly-experienced developers that wrote the kernel were rubbish.'  I'm not normally into book-burning, but...

Comment: @chill how do I go about sleeping the threads between queues, I guess I would do it with semaphores again?

Comment: sleeping and looping-to-wait are both concepts you should abandon when you start to write multithreaded apps. Threads should either be executing work or waiting on a synchronisation primitive (mutex, semaphore). The waiting part is taken care of by the OS's scheduler, not by you spinning and checking anything.

Comment: @MattMunson - Listen to @chill/RobH and Google for 'C++ producer consumer queue' - there are loads of examples out there.  A very simple implementation would be any queue class with a mutex and a semaphore.  In the producer thread/s, get the mutex, push on your work, release the mutex, signal the semaphore.  In the consumer threads/s, wait on the semaphore, then get the mutex, pop an item of work, release the mutex.  Usually, in OO languages like C++, the work item is a class instance with data and methods for the threads to call when they get a work instance.

Answer (score 1):

If main() is waiting on pthread_join then (assuming that on your platform it isn't implemented as just a spin lock) it will cause no CPU load; If pthread_join is waiting on a mutex then the scheduler won't give that thread any time until that mutex is signalled.

If N truly is the number of cores then maybe you should forget about managing the thread scheduling yourself; The OS scheduler will take care of that. If N is less than the number or cores, perhaps you could set thread affinity to run your process on N cores only (or spawn a calculation process which does that, if you don't want to set thread affinity for the rest of your process); Again, the point of doing this would be to let the OS scheduler deal with scheduling.

Comment: I read somewhere that there are/can be limits to how many threads the OS will allow at once, both per process and system-wide total. What if the number of threads I need to run is greater than that? It seems like limiting # of threads to # of cores is an easy and practical way around that.

Comment: @Matt Munson - there is a limit and is very large. Within one process on a 32-bit system, developers ususally run into virtual adddress space limitiations first because of the ridiculously large stack space usually allocated for thread stacks. The Windows box on which I post this has 1036 threads loaded in total at the moment, top process 'sidebar.exe' - 68 threads.  Performance is fine.  Linux will be similar.

Comment: If you were thinking of creating one thread for each of a large number of tasks, that would be A Bad Idea, because as @MartinJames says there is a memory cost (stack space per thread) and also a thread startup time cost. I'd heartily recommend a work queue as per chill's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd most definitely look at OpenMP or C++11 `async`. To be honest, at this point I think that OpenMP is more viable.

#### *OpenMP*

Here is a quick example that will sometimes find the correct answer (`42`) randomly, using 2 threads.

Note that if you leave out the `omp.h` include and the call to `omp_set_num_threads(2);` you'll get the native number of threads (i.e. depending on the number of cores available at runtime). OpenMP also let's you configure this number dynamically by setting the environment variable e.g. `OMP_NUM_THREADS=16`. Indeed you can dynamically disable parallelism in whole :)

> <sub>I even threw in a sample thread parameter and result accumulation - this is usually where things become a little more interesting then just kicking off a job and forgetting about it. Then again, it may be overkill for your question :)</sub>

Compiled with `g++ -fopenmp test.cpp -o test`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <omp.h>

int find_num(int w)
{
    return rand() % 100;
}

int main ()
{
    srand(time(0));

    omp_set_num_threads(2); // optional! leave it out to get native number of threads

    bool found = false;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction (|:found)
    for(int w=0; w<30; w++)
    {
        if (!found) 
        {
             found = (find_num(w) == 42);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "number was found: " << (found? "yes":"no") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: looks cool. I'm not familiar with some of the syntax though. What does that `#pragma` macro do?

Comment: @MattMunson: read all about it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), [GNU OpenMP](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/gomp/), and [various other compiler vendor documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Fruprpdir.htm). Note that OpenMP is standard, portable and has implementations for C, C++, Fortran (more?)

Comment: Oh... not my favourite: http://openmp.org/wp/; Blogs are surprisingly good introductions: [Thinking Parallel](http://www.thinkingparallel.com) and this post [http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0054/](OpenMP Traps For C++ Developers); Yes, reading the traps was the best introduction for me :)

Comment: does the above code start one thread per iteration of the loop or two? Its important that I be able to pass a different argument for each thread.

Comment: @mattmunson: no, omp works with _thread teams_ and schedules the work without creating new threads. Look closely how my sample already passses the loop variable (w) to find_num

Comment: I don't really get it. What is happening at each `found |= find_num(w) == 42;`?

Comment: @MattMunson: With the simplest possible scheduling across two threads, thread #1 will do `find_num` for w=[0..15) and thread #2 will handle w=[15..30); In practice you can have much more dynamic scheduling: It is all very well documented in the links. The important thing is that all the complexity is hidden (unless you want to override the defaults) and OpenMP is a portable standard. **Update** _I simplified the (not so relevant) use of the `|=` operator._

Comment: why would you do the first 15 to one thread, and the latter 15 to the other, wouldn't that be counter to parallelism? But if I understand correctly, the loop code isn't interpreted using conventional C++ semantics, and the program doesn't wait for find_num(w) to return a value before it carries on with the loop. Because if it does wait I don't see how this can be parallel.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4634/discussion-between-sehe-and-matt-munson)

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to have a global variable that gets set when a thread is done, and the main loop polls that variable to check when the tread is done and only does `pthread_join` then.

Comment: I guess that polling would be done with a loop. Would incessant looping of that sort be a drain on the CPU?

Comment: @MattMunson: If you add some kind of sleep (see `man usleep` for example) in the loop, it won't be noticeable.

Comment: How would I know how long to sleep for?

Comment: Introducing arbitrary delays before allowing the program to do more work contradicts with the goal of performance improvement via the maximum effective degree of parallelization. Polling is only justified in very very limited number of cases, when it can spare the overheads of trapping into the kernel doing a context switch. Polling with a timeout is the very very last resort and generally indicates a failure to design a proper algorithm.

Comment: @chill: I didn't say my solution was good, just that it's simple.